# IndexedDB is automatically being recovered after app installation

Tags: android, cordova, indexeddb

following problem: I'm running a Cordova-based hybrid app and use IndexedDB as my data storage. On iOS everything's fine, but on Android there's the problem, that on some devices this data is being restored after a new installation of the app. I have tried two different ways to clean-up the data: manually executing .clear() on every storage and telling IndexedDB to completely remove the database using the .deleteDatabase() method. Afterwards I opened the Chrome dev tools and took a look into the application data -> all data were erased...until removing and re-installing the app! It's not the latest data that is being restored...some data from Nov '16. And I have absolutely no idea where this data comes from.

For your information: I'm ruinning the application on Android 7.0 and deliver Crosswalk 23 with it which is based on Chromium 52.

Best regards

Sven

Answer (score 2):

Since Android 6.0 the `android:allowBackup` property is set to `true` by default and this is why your data persist when uninstalling the app.

You can change that either by the `manifest` file of android or `config.xml` of your cordova application.

This is how you set the property from config.xml:

```
<config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
  <application android:allowBackup="false"></application>
</config-file>
```